# Jtextfield search in database msql using keylistener

Tags: java, mysql, swing

When I write I'm looking for the name in the database in `JTextField`, I would like pressing enter show me all the corresponding names. Unfortunately I can not do it, someone can help me please .

```
public class Rechercher extends JFrame{

    private JLabel rechercher;
    private JTextField trechercher;
    private JButton executer;
    private JButton exit;
    static Connection connection;
    Vector titrecolonnes = new Vector();
    Vector donnee = new Vector();
    private JTable table;
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

    public Rechercher()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        trechercher = new JTextField("");
        add(trechercher);
        trechercher.setBounds(140, 30, 235,35);
        executer = new JButton("Rechercher :");
        add(executer);
        executer.setBounds(10, 34, 115,25);
        try
         {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             System.out.println("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver found");
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eva","root","");
             System.out.println("Connexion Ok");
         }catch(Exception cnfe)
        {
                System.out.println("Error:"+cnfe.getMessage());
                }

        //-----actionner textfield
                trechercher.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
                {
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

                        trechercher.setText("");

                }

                }); 

        //------Connection à la base de donneés
        trechercher.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                try{

                       //  Read data from a table
                       String sql = "SELECT * FROM impaye";
                       Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                       ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                       int columns = md.getColumnCount();

                       //  Get column names 
                       for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                       {
                          titrecolonnes.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
                       }

                       //  Get row data
                       while (rs.next()) 
                       {
                          Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                          for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                          {
                             row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                          }
                          donnee.addElement(row);
                       }
                       rs.close();
                       stmt.close();
                }catch(Exception cnfe)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error:"+cnfe.getMessage());
                    }

                TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (donnee, titrecolonnes)
                {
                public Class getColumnClass(int columnNames) {
                    Class returnValue;
                    if ((columnNames >= 0) && (columnNames < getColumnCount())) {
                      returnValue = getValueAt(0, columnNames).getClass();
                    } else {
                      returnValue = Object.class;
                    }
                    return returnValue;
                  }
                };
                table = new JTable (model) ; 
                sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model) ; 
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane((table));
                table.setRowSorter (sorter) ; 
                getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: Hi @Recay, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is not completely clear. Are you trying to provide search suggestions from a database, based on the current user input?

Answer (score 1):

```
trechercher.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
```

Don't use a KeyListener.

A `JTextField` was designed to be used with an `ActionListener` to handle the Enter key.

```
table = new JTable (model) ; 
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model) ;    
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane((table));
table.setRowSorter (sorter) ; 
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

The above code is creating new components to add to the GUI. The problem is all components will have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. When you dynamically add components to a visible GUI then the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // invokes the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // repaints the components
```

However an easier solution is to add empty table and scrollpane to the frame in the constructor of your class. Then when you get new data all you need to do is refresh the `TableModel` of the table and the table will repaint itself.

Then all you need to do in your refresh method is:

```
table.setModel(model );
```